# Get a data in a database?

Tags: php, sql

I would like to get the registered IP of a user in my database.

I use this method :

```
$securityRes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM security WHERE userName=".$userRow['name']);
$securityRow=mysql_fetch_array($securityRes);
```

But it return me nothing, when I use this code :

```
echo $securityRow['IP']
```

I'm blocked on it since like 1 hours, and Google seems to don't want to be my friend today :/

So I ask help here, hoping I will get some.

Thank you in advance; cordially, Matt.

[PS - Here is my database | my table "security" :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Osoh.png)

[image]

Comment: use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`.

Comment: show us the result of `var_dump($securityRow);`

Comment: what is the value of `$userRow['name']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all **use mysqli_* instead of mysql_***. And the issue is here:

```
"SELECT * FROM security WHERE userName=".$userRow['name'];
```

`name` is always a string, and for string comparison you have to bind the value in single quotes like:

```
"SELECT * FROM security WHERE userName='".$userRow['name']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try debugging here.

```
$securityRes    =    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM security WHERE userName=".$userRow['name']) or die(mysql_error());
$securityRow    =    mysql_fetch_array($securityRes);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($securityRow); // Check your result
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

1) In your code you need string to be enclosed by single quotes.

2) Try to use `prepared statement or PDO` like this

```
        //db connection

     global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM security WHERE userName=?");

        $stmt->bind_param('s',$userRow['name']);

        The argument may be one of four types:

            i - integer
            d - double
            s - string
            b - BLOB
        //change it by respectively 

        $stmt->execute();
        $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

        $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

        if($row_count>0)
        {

         print_r($get_result->fetch_assoc());

        }
```